# $J$-homomorphism for unitary group

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

We can define the $J$-homomorphism
$$ J: \pi_{r}(SO(n)) \rightarrow \pi_{r+q}(S^q) $$
Can we define 
$$ J: \pi_{r}(U(n)) \rightarrow \pi_{r+q}(S^q) $$
what information can we deduce in this situation about homotopy groups of spheres?

Answer (score 4):

First of all note that the homotopy groups of $O(n)$ are the same as that of $SO(n)$. Then the natural inclusion $U(n) \subset O(2n)$ gives an induced map on homotopy. In the colimit this gives the complex $J$-homomorphism $\pi_i(U) \to \pi_i^S$. According to Ravenel "this is well known to coincide up to a factor of 2 with that of the real $J$-homomorphism" (Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres - pp. 168)